# Deleting a value at a time by it's location which is separated by a comma in column of a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

[This is table that has all the skills which candidate can add to their profile in candidate table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0uxi.png)

[And this is where candidate has added desired skills which is separated by comma,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NzjX.png)

Now i am stuck , problem is how can i delete those skills which i dont want anymore to be in my profile. This is separated by a comma that's why i am finding it delete individualy

```
$sql_r = "select expert_skills, inter_skills, beginner_skills 
            from user_personal_details 
            WHERE upd_user_id = '". $_SESSION["user_id"] ."'";

$skills_render = $this->model->execute_query_all($sql_r);


$arr1=explode(",",$skills_render['0']['expert_skills']);

$ty = array_keys($arr1);
$ty1 = array_values($arr1);

$location = $_POST['skill_location'];

echo $location;
```

$location variable i.e skill id, i am taking from front end, how can i delete by location

Comment: And that's why you should normalize your database...

Comment: try to save the data as JSON array [See here](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-json-data-fields-mysql-databases/)

Comment: Seems like a self inflicted wound to me. Still now you know why it is a bad idea to store indexes in a comma seperated list in a single column

Comment: You can use array_diff( [3, 2, 1, 5], [2] ) will result in [3, 1, 5]

Comment: Actually this is bad practice try to avoid this type of database structure. For solution you can manage through php arrays but its lengthy process.

Comment: Thanks everyone, @RiggsFolly I am just beginner , if this is bad way to do  then what would be better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_diff( [3, 2, 1, 5], [2] ) will result in [3, 1, 5]

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize your database.
Or for each delete action, update the entire value in skills.
if you want to remove one item individually, you need to update the field with new set of values. 
you have 1,2,9,10,7,6,8 as expert_skills. if you need to remove 9 & 10 then you need to update it as 1,2,7,6,8.

I assume you don't have a delete screen but an update screen where you select/unselect the skills.

Comment: Can someone please let me know why the above answer is down voted. I think the approach @waq followed is not the coorect one. I should have suggested better options. But, I think he already built the logic. based on his other questions, it looks like he is not an expert. so, he may not be able to solve this quickly. that is why I answered to his approach of development. If someone let me know the reason to down vote my answer so that i will consider those points when I answer in the future.

Comment: Because at best it is just a comment. It makes no attempt to answer the question. _I should have suggested better options_ Yes an answer should make some attempt at providing a solution to the question and describing what was done and why it was done

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly for your feedback. I will consider your point when i post my next answer. but I dont see much difference between the 2 answers here. one upvoted & one downvoted